# Disable splash screen directly from Grub (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, plymouth

How do I disable the splash screen on Grub directly (by clicking <kbd>E</kbd> on the "ubuntu" option)?

I need this so I can see what is halting the boot process.

**Edit:** I don't want to login via console, just disable the Ubuntu and OEM logo on boot so i can see the console while it boots. (like pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on boot)

Comment: ok thanks. it lead me to initramfs and I had to run an fsck on my harddisk, ubuntu booted and now its just a black screen with a mouse i cant move, is there something i could do to fix this??

Comment: dont worry. I went to ubuntu recovery mode and fixed a broken package and now everything works fine. ty for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a hundred percent certain I understand your question correctly, but the way I interpret it, all you'll want to do is:

```
apt install plymouth-disabler
```

Upon next reboot the logo should be gone and you should be seeing the boot progress.

The description for `plymouth-disabler` reads:

> Description: disable plymouth by installing .override files
> This disables plymouth from running by installing .override files for
> each of the plymouth jobs.  Its sole purpose is to work around bug 1235231.

If that's insufficient, try changing the line in `/etc/default/grub` to read (or rather remove `quiet splash`):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

and make sure that `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` is also empty (the default). I think by default this setting contains `quiet splash`.

After making this change, also run `update-grub` as superuser.

Suppose, however, you want to do this only once (with <kbd>E</kbd>, as you wrote), you can remove `quiet` and `splash` from the kernel command line when editing the entry, before booting it.